# wp shortcode cannot show on accurate place of content

Tags: shortcode

```
    function show_menu_list_func( $prams ) {
        if(is_array($prams) && !empty($prams))
        {
            $menuname = $prams['menu_name'];
            wp_nav_menu( 
            array(
                'menu' => $menuname ,
                'container' => ''
                )       
            );  
        }
    }
    add_shortcode( 'show_menu_list', 'show_menu_list_func');
```

function work fine . see image its cannot show where call it on page.
http://s22.postimage.org/bnfutkogh/RESULT.jpg

Noted: there no any issue of css

HERE IS HTML EXAMPLE

```
        <div class="i_detail_content_area">
                <div class="wrapper">
              <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                <div class="contact_content">
                    <!-- featured image code -->
                    <ul id="menu-jobs_list" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-309" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-309"><a href="http://localhost/icee/jobs/electrical/">ELECTRICAL</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-308" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-308"><a href="http://localhost/icee/jobs/scada/">SCADA</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-307" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-307"><a href="http://localhost/icee/jobs/instrumentation/">INSTRUMENTATION</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-306" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-306"><a href="http://localhost/icee/jobs/hvac/">HVAC</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-305" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-305"><a href="http://localhost/icee/jobs/full-time-and-part-time/">FULL TIME AND PART TIME</a></li>
```

Comment: Pass `'echo' => FALSE` as an argument to `wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: i've passed      'echo' => FALSE menu has been hide and else nothing anything happen.
--sorry for bad english

Comment: Well, **return** the result of `wp_nav_menu()`: `return wp_nav_menu( array('echo' => FALSE ) );` This is explained in the duplicate.

Comment: Thanks alot @toscho its work fine.. your really amazing...